# delegate is deduced to void when calling template function in D(LDC2)

Tags: templates, d, type-inference

I have a custom `Option` type written using `Algebraic`.

```
struct None{};
struct Some(T){
    T t;

    alias t this;

    T get(){
        return t;
    }
};

alias Option(T) = Algebraic!(Some!(T), None);
Option!T some(T)(T t){
    return Option!T(Some!T(t));
}
Option!T none(T)(){
    return Option!T(None());
}
```

Then I try to write some basic convenience functions:

```
T getValue(T,uint size)(VariantN!(size, Some!T, None) opt){
    return opt.get!(Some!T).t;
}

bool isDefined(T, uint size)(VariantN!(size, Some!T, None) opt){
    return opt.convertsTo!(Some!T);
}

A match(A,T,uint size)(VariantN!(size, Some!T, None) opt, A delegate(T) some, A delegate() none){
    if(opt.isDefined!(T,size)){
        return some(opt.getValue!(T,size));
    }else{
        return none();
    }
}
```

When calling `match` compiler fails to deduce correct arguments to template:

```
 Option!int test = some(1);
 bool boolReturn = test.match((x) => false, () => true);
```

With error:

```
    Error: template util.match cannot deduce function from argument types !()(VariantN!(4LU, Some!int, None), void, bool function() pure nothrow @nogc @safe), candidates are:
src/util.d(79,3):        util.match(A, T, uint size)(VariantN!(size, Some!T, None) opt, A delegate(T) some, A delegate() none)
```

The error output states that the second argument to `match` ( meaning `bool delegate(int)` or `(x) => false` ) is deduced to `void`. Why ?

This example compiles (all the same but type of x is explicitly given):

```
Option!int test = some(1);
bool boolReturn = test.match((int x) => false, () => true);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the type names aren't given in a delegate, it makes it as a template (which is typed void in the error message) which will have an inferred type when it is instantiated.... and here it wants to be inferred to type T, which itself is an inferred argument based on the arguments.

The problem is the compiler is trying to infer for the (x) => template and at the same time infer for the function call and doesn't know which one to do first, so it can't look deep enough. If you explicitly mention it in either place, it breaks the cycle:

// works
 bool boolReturn = test.match!(bool, int)((x) => false, () => true);

or

// works
test.match((int x) => false)

But I'm not sure about how to do it automatically... I've tried decoupling them with different arrangements, but no luck yet....

The way Phobos usually gets around this is by putting the delegates in as `alias` template params instead of a runtime arguments. Change the signature to:

```
typeof(none()) match(alias some, alias none, T, uint size)(VariantN!(size, Some!T, None) opt) {
```

And change the call to:

```
 bool boolReturn = test.match!((x) => false, () => true);
```

And that compiles because you moved the inference to two layers: first, the compiler accepts those delegates, still in template form, as arguments. Then it accepts `test` and figures out its type to infer the other arguments. Then it moves into the body and actually sees the *call* to `some`, and instantiates its argument type at that point, inside the body. So it works because that inferred type is done after type T is already known from the signature layer, outside the body.

But as to do it without the template function.... I don't know, I think the solution is to do two layers so the explicit type is named in one or the other, but i just haven't figured that out yet (and tbh will prolly stop trying cuz i have other things to do now).

Comment: Two layer approach works nicely. Thanks for sharing :)